# AutoMapper with DI: Cannot create an instance of type... When using a ValueResolver

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have a **.NET Core 3.1** API with the following Nuget packages:

- **AutoMapper** (10.1.1)
- **AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection** (8.1.1)

I'm trying to map a value from an entity to a dto using a **ValueResolver** and I'm having an exception:

> AutoMapperMappingException: Cannot create an instance of type TestAutomapperResolver.Mapping.CustomResolver

Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => cfg.AddMaps(typeof(TestProfile).Assembly));
}
```

TestProfile.cs

```
public class TestProfile : Profile
{
    public TestProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<TestEntity, TestDto>()
            .ForMember(src => src.PropertyToBeMappedByResolver, opts => opts.MapFrom<CustomResolver>());
    }
}

public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<TestEntity, TestDto, string>
{
    public string Resolve(TestEntity source, TestDto destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return "String generated with resolver";
    }
}
```

When doing `mapper.CreateMap<TestDto>(entity);` I'm receiving that exception.

By the way, using this resolver as `opts => opts.MapFrom(CustomResolver())` is not an option because I want to inject some service into that resolver.

Any idea?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I read this obviously. I am missing something?

Comment: Nah I dont think you're missing anything. It really feels like this should be working, and I'm not sure why. I brought your code down and can confirm the error.

Comment: Clearly your code is nothing like the example in the docs, so if you read that page, how come you wrote that code? Why? :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu which part it's not like that? Did you clone my repo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `AddMaps` when you shouldn't be. `AddMaps` just adds profiles and mappings, but doesn't add all the extra services that the DI package does.

This will do it properly:

```cs
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(TestProfile).Assembly);
```

Now, AutoMapper gives you a very unhelpful error here, but the issue goes back to Microsoft Dependency injection. The DI doesn't know about your custom resolver type, so it doesn't even try.

Since you didn't use the DI package's extension method, the resolver doesn't get added to the service collection. You can manually add these services if needed:

```cs
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => cfg.AddMaps(typeof(TestProfile).Assembly));
services.AddTransient<CustomResolver>();
```

Comment: The AM DI package [does that](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/a7a3ad6bac01badf6e3e6aca5fad97d5639d8adf/test/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Tests/TypeResolutionTests.cs#L47) already.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I know, and it's not working for me, I'm asking why...

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but if that test is passing, then you _must_ be doing smth wrong.

Comment: Ok now I'm confused. How does this not answer the question? If I take your sample and run it, I get the exception. If I add that second line, injecting the CustomResolver into the DI, it converts the object without error.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu check my edit. You're correct, but he was not calling the method you thought he was calling.

Comment: `AddMaps` has no place here. The DI package is to be used as the example in the docs. So please remove the initial code.

Comment: I'll make an edit to emphasize the proper solution, but I'm not going to delete the part about `AddMaps`. My answer correctly answers the question as given, and if anyone comes along having code like the OP, they should be given the extra context.

Comment: @AdamSchiavone hi Adam. Your solution is correct, thank you so much! I lost a lot of hours and I was not seeing clearly what I was doing wrong. I knew it should work that way. Anyways as Lucian said I would delete the second part. I was not asking to do it manually but to be done automatically.