# AutoMapper with Custom Type Converter and DI throws AutoMapperMappingException

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I'm examining a project which uses `AutoMapper` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. All
Mappers works as expected, but for one - the *only* one - which uses a **custom type converter**.

```
// there is some abstractions here, but MapperProfileProvider inherits AutoMapper.Profile
public class Mappings : MapperProfileProvider
{
    public Mappings()
    {
        CreateMap<MyItemTypeA, MyItemTypeB>().ConvertUsing<MyItemTypeConverter>();
        CreateMap<MyItemTypeB, MyItemTypeA>().ConvertUsing<MyItemTypeConverter>();
    }

    public class MyItemTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<MyItemTypeA, MyItemTypeB>,
        ITypeConverter<MyItemTypeB, MyItemTypeA>
    {
        public MyItemTypeB Convert(MyItemTypeA source, MyItemTypeB destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            // do the conversion and return
            return new MyItemTypeB()
            {
                // assignments...
            };
        }

        public MyItemTypeA Convert(MyItemTypeB source, MyItemTypeA destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            // do the conversion and return
            return new MyItemTypeA()
            {
                // assignments...
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The mapper is injected into the class where it is used.

```
internal class MyApiService : ApiServiceBase
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public MyApiService(IMapper mapper) { _mapper = mapper; }

    public async Task<object> Post(MyRequest request)
    {
        // here the exception occurs
        var myItemA = _mapper.Map<MyItemTypeA>(request.ItemB);
    }
}
```

Using the custom type mapper throws `AutoMapperMappingException: Cannot create an instance of type MyTypeConverter`

I'm almost sure this issue is related to DI. The DI does not know about and/or cannot create an instance of the type converter. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67691277/1638842) pointed me into that direction:

> The DI doesn't know about your custom resolver type, so it doesn't even try.
> Since you didn't use the DI package's extension method, the resolver doesn't get added to the service collection. You can manually add these services if needed

Besides manually adding the service, the answer recommends using `services.AddAutoMapper`. Which is what I am doing. The `AddAutoMapper` code looks like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper((IServiceProvider f, IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg) =>
{
    foreach (var profile in f.GetService<IEnumerable<IMapperProfileProvider>>())
    {
        cfg.AddProfile((Profile)profile);
    }
}, new Assembly[] { });
```

(There are some abstractions here, too. But I believe it's compliant with the sample in the [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core))

What I've tried:

When explicitly adding `MyItemTypeConverter` as a service using `services.AddScoped<MyTypeConverter>();` the mapping works.

Also I found the following from the AutoMapper [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html)

> And supply AutoMapper with either an instance of a custom type converter, or simply the type, which AutoMapper will instantiate at run time. The mapping configuration for our above source/destination types then becomes:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<string, int>().ConvertUsing(s => Convert.ToInt32(s));
  cfg.CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeTypeConverter());
  cfg.CreateMap<string, Type>().ConvertUsing<TypeTypeConverter>();
  cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
});
```

Line 3 caught my attention, which supplies an instance to the AutoMapper. If I use that, it works too.

```
CreateMap<MyItemTypeA, MyItemTypeB>().ConvertUsing(new MyItemTypeConverter());
CreateMap<MyItemTypeB, MyItemTypeA>().ConvertUsing(new MyItemTypeConverter());
```

So supplying an instance or adding the type converter as service works. I can't get my head around it. Why can't the type converter be instantiated at run time? The docs suggest it's possible ("... or simply the type, which AutoMapper will instantiate at run time). Why doesn't the DI know about the custom type converter? What am I missing?

Comment: No, see https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks for pointing me to the docks. I've seen it, but can't get my head around it. I added the `AddAutoMapper` code to the question. Could you go into more detail? Also following your link through to https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection states that the package has been deprecated. That confuses me. Is it to be used in my case?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I edited the question for more clarity and added more of the code. Also I found that passing an instance of the custom type converter solves the problem too. Still I do not get why supplying "only" the type throws the error. Any help appreciated. THX

Comment: Obviously your code is nothing like the docs, that's why it doesn`t work.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Could you be a little more precise and point me into the direction? I'd really appreciate that. Is it the `AddAutoMapper` part?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The reason the type converter was not being instantiated at run time, is that it is in a different assembly, and therefore not found. It's so clear now...

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

> You define the configuration using profiles. And then you let AutoMapper know in what assemblies are those profiles defined by calling the IServiceCollection extension method AddAutoMapper at startup.

I finally used this override

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IServiceProvider, IMapperConfigurationExpression> configAction, params Assembly[] assemblies)
        => AddAutoMapperClasses(services, configAction, assemblies);
```

and passed the assemblies to it

```
var assemblies = new Assembly[]
{
    typeof(typeFromAssembly1).Assembly,
    typeof(typeFromAssembly2).Assembly
};

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper((IServiceProvider f, IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg) =>
{
    foreach (var profile in f.GetService<IEnumerable<IMapperProfileProvider>>())
    {
        cfg.AddProfile((Profile)profile);
    }
}, assemblies);
```

Comment: This only works well if your profiles are in a different assembly than your resolvers, converters etc. If you pass the profiles' assembly, maps will be created twice (once by your code and once by AddAutoMapper), quite wasteful. The problem here is that you do DI in profiles. See https://www.jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/